# How to detect if folder or file was opened electron/node

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, fs

I'm trying to get folder's/file's name when I open those, tryed to handle a `fs.watch` event but it only works when I rename add or remove the file/folder in folder on which I was handled
`fs.watch`,
for example:

```js
//with that code I can only see the changes of files in "FileStorage" folder, but not the action when I open files in it
fs.watch("C:/FileStorage", (eventType, filename) => {
        console.log("\nThe file", filename, "was modified!");
        console.log("The type of change was:", eventType);
 });
```

have any idea how to do that?

Comment: are you assuming that you are the only application that can open said file/folder? because the most you can do is use hashes to track if they were edited but if they were merely opened? hmm

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve here?  There is no generic OS notification  when a file is opened.  This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you're asking us a question about a potential solution to some problem, but not telling us what the real problem is.

Comment: may [this](stackoverflow.com/a/28588960/7574023) can be useful

Comment: @jfriend00 @The Bomb Squad
, the problem is that I have an application with electronjs and in it I have the script ```fs.watch``` wich is on the folder I have created before and I need to detect all actions that happened in that folder, mostly I need to see in console of my app which folder or file have been opened

Comment: Why? What is the real problem you're trying to solve here?  You still aren't telling us the REAL problem.

Comment: If it's your own app that you're trying to instrument, I'd probably just suggest putting logging code into your own app which can log to a debug console or can log to your other apps console with your favorite interprocess communications.  I don't know of any way to log what you're asking for from outside the app.

Answer (score 0):

`fs.watch()` doesn't watch for file-opening events, unfortunately.